# Problem while passing value from Javascript to java(backing bean)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

so I need store value of a javascript variable in my Java backing bean,as the value of variables get lost in case the page refreshes,so I used Primefaces to do that,but facing a problem..I will post my entire code to avoid confusion.

First I defined:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Then in xhtml:

```
<p:remoteCommand name ="svf" actionListener="#{bean.defmethod}">
```

In javascipt:

```
svf([{name="String1",value = str1}]);
```

In java:

```
public void defmethod(){

String s1=Facescontext.getexternalInstance......

}
```

But its throwing an error saying bean does not have the property defmethod.

Please help.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Did you try `actionListener="#{bean.defmethod()}"`?